# How to convert d/MM/yyyy data to dd/MM/yyyy in sql server table?

Tags: date

I have create one field in sql server database as nvarchar datatype and store some date like 'd/MM/yyyy' and 'dd/MM/yyyy' format previously. Now i want to get all data in 'dd/MM/yyyy' format using query it is possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more useful to just change the field type to DATE?

Comment: Are you saying that **all** of the dates in this column are currently formatted as `d/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: no kev i store using one application d/MM/yyyy format and using another one application dd/MM/yyyy format (database is same for two application)....i got solution using below query

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the field to `datetime` in the query:

```
select cast(YourField as datetime)
from YourTable
where isdate(YourField) = 1
```

The `where isdate(YourField) = 1` part is necessary to filter out rows where the value is no valid date (it's a `nvarchar` field, so there could be things like `abc` in some rows!)

But you should really change the field to `datetime` in the long term, as already suggested by Christopher in his comment.
Casting like described above is always error-prone because of the many different data formats in different countries.

For example, I live in Germany where the official date format is `dd.mm.yyyy`.
So today (December 9th) is `9.12.2011`, and running `select cast('9.12.2011' as datetime)` on my machine returns the correct datetime value.

Another common format is `mm/dd/yyyy`, so December 9th would be `12/9/2011`.
Now imagine I have a nvarchar field with a date in this format on my German machine:
`select cast('12/9/2011' as datetime)` **will return September 12th (instead of December 9th)!**

Issues like this can easily be avoided by using the proper type for the column, in this case `datetime`.

Comment: Thanks Christopher and christian i have already 30,000 records in that table so currently not able to update field so i can get dd/MM/yyyy using below query ` select RIGHT('00'+ CAST(SUBSTRING(FIELDNAME,CHARINDEX('/',FIELDNAME)-2,2) as varchar(2)),2) + RIGHT('00'+ CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(FIELDNAME,CHARINDEX('/',FIELDNAME)+1,2),'/','') as varchar(2)),2) + SUBSTRING(FIELDNAME,len(FIELDNAME)-3,4)+ as [DATEFIELD] from TABLENAME `